# Comparing Street Address to ESRI spatial file

Tags: sql, tableau-api, shapefile, esri

I have a list of street address information that I would like to compare against an ESRI shape file that I downloaded from `us.census.gov`. Basically I am trying to determine if any addresses on my list fall into any of the regions within the ESRI shape file.

`us.census.gov` has a tool to retrieve geo coordinates by processing my address list, but I'm not sure on what column or columns I would use to compare.

It would be awesome if this can be done with SQL some how. But if there is another language that I may be able to leverage such as R or Python, let me know. I also have access to the desktop version of tableau in case someone might know how to do this in tableau. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what SQL you are using, but the common way here is to store the Esri shape as a polygon, then use the appropriate function to check if a point is within that polygon (resolve your address to a lat lon and check if thats in the polygon).  Unfortunately I can't be any more detailed than that without knowing what database type you are using (these functions vary heavily between databases)

Comment: Thanks @Twelfth. I am using SQLServer2014 but have access to 2016 if needed.  Following your comment that it can be done with SQL, I did a quick search and found an old article that references the following software [OGR2OGR](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/ogr2ogr-patterns-for-sql-server/) for working with SQL Server. wondering if it's still necessary today as the article is from 2012.

Comment: To anyone that is looking to solve a similar question as this, I highly recommend the book, "Pro Spatial With SQL Server 2012" by Alastair Aitchison". It helped me arrive at the solution.  It walks you from importing the ESRI Shape file all the way to different t-sql syntax one may use.  More importantly you walk away with a good understanding spatial analysis.  Lastly for those that want to do their own research, the syntax I ended up using involved the t-sql term, "STIntersects".